# TypeScript type for onLayout event in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

How can I specify a type in TypeScript for React Native's onLayout event?

```
  const handleOnLayout = (e: SomeTypeHere) => {
    // stuff
  };

  <View onLayout={handleOnLayout}>
    <Text>Hi</Text>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This method returns a `LayoutChangeEvent` with these properties `{nativeEvent: { layout: {x, y, width, height}}}`

Import with:

```
import { LayoutChangeEvent } from "react-native";
```

[Source](https://github.com/bgrieder/react-native-typescript-definitions/blob/e2e94708a85a7691200275a23c06e2f52afe8106/typings/react-native/react-native.d.ts#L1618)

Answer (score 1):

Murmletiers link to the source was helpful! I am using `LayoutRectangle` now as it is the type definition that I was looking for:

```
   export interface LayoutRectangle {
        x: number;
        y: number;
        width: number;
        height: number;
    }

    // @see TextProperties.onLayout
    export interface LayoutChangeEvent {
        nativeEvent: {
            layout: LayoutRectangle
        }
    }
```

used like this

```
import { LayoutRectangle } from "react-native";

const [layout, setLayout] = useState<LayoutRectangle>();
```